# renderHighcharts vs renderUI; Which one is faster when rendering several plots

Tags: shiny, highcharts, grid-layout, r-highcharter, profvis

I am building an App that at some point renders 7-16 Highcharts in a grid-layout.
The rendering of these Highcharts is quite slow and I am trying to make it faster.

Right now I am using renderUI(), htmlOutput() and highcharter::hw_grid() to render the graphs. ( See Code chunk 1)
I have come upon this [Post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/speed-concerns-renderhighchart-vs-renderui/52339/2) where they tried to improve the performance by first using highcharter::renderHighchart() to render the Graphs and then using highcharter::higchartOutput() in renderUI() function.  I have changed the code a bit so that it's output is the same as in my first Version, but the Idea should have stayed the same.(see Code chunk 2)

I have now Implemented both versions in two shiny-Apps and tried to evaluate them with profvis. I am very new to profvis and i am not sure where to look exactly to compare these two options. So I have just looked at the total time RunApp() takes. My first Version using renderUI() and htmlOutput() seemst to be faster than version two. This contradicts the results of the beforementioned [Post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/speed-concerns-renderhighchart-vs-renderui/52339/2).

Now I am wondering which options is faster and why. Should I change my code from Version 1 to version 2 to improve performance?

### Code Chunk 1

```
samp <- sample(5000, 100, replace = TRUE)
library("highcharter")
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    htmlOutput('plots')
))



server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    

    
    output$plots <- renderUI({
        
        output=list()
        for (i in 1:50) {
            n <- i # Make local variable
            plotname <- paste("plot", n , sep="")
            
            output[[plotname]] <- 
                highchart() %>%
                hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
                hc_title(text = "renderHighchart()") %>%
                hc_xAxis(categories = seq_along(samp)) %>%
                hc_add_series(
                    data = samp,
                    name = "Downloads"
                )
        }
        hw_grid(output,ncol=3)
    })
})

app=shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)

profvis::profvis(runApp(app))
```

### Code chunk 2

```
samp <- sample(5000, 100, replace = TRUE)
library("highcharter")
library(shiny)


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    uiOutput('plots')
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    
    n.col <- 3
    
    output$plots <- renderUI({
        col.width <- round(12/n.col) # Calculate bootstrap column width
        n.row <- ceiling(50/n.col) # calculate number of rows
        cnter <<- 0 # Counter variable
        
        # Create row with columns
        rows  <- lapply(1:n.row,function(row.num){
            cols  <- lapply(1:n.col, function(i) {
                cnter    <<- cnter + 1
                plotname <- paste("plot", cnter, sep="")
                column(col.width, highchartOutput(plotname))
            }) 
            fluidRow( do.call(tagList, cols) )
        })
        
        do.call(tagList, rows)
    })
    
    for (i in 1:50) {
        local({
            n <- i # Make local variable
            plotname <- paste("plot", n , sep="")
            output[[plotname]] <- renderHighchart({
                highchart() %>%
                    hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
                    hc_title(text = "renderHighchart()") %>%
                    hc_xAxis(categories = seq_along(samp)) %>%
                    hc_add_series(
                        data = samp,
                        name = "Downloads"
                    )
            })
        })
    }
})

app=shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)

profvis::profvis(runApp(app))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now put the two options in one app

```
samp <- sample(5000, 100, replace = TRUE)
library("highcharter")
library(shiny)


ui <- shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
    fluidRow(uiOutput('plots')),
    fluidRow(htmlOutput('rUI')))
)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    
    n.col <- 3
    
    output$plots <- renderUI({
        col.width <- round(12/n.col) # Calculate bootstrap column width
        n.row <- ceiling(50/n.col) # calculate number of rows
        cnter <<- 0 # Counter variable
        
        # Create row with columns
        rows  <- lapply(1:n.row,function(row.num){
            cols  <- lapply(1:n.col, function(i) {
                cnter    <<- cnter + 1
                plotname <- paste("plot", cnter, sep="")
                column(col.width, highchartOutput(plotname))
            }) 
            fluidRow( do.call(tagList, cols) )
        })
        
        do.call(tagList, rows)
    })
    
    for (i in 1:50) {
        local({
            n <- i # Make local variable
            plotname <- paste("plot", n , sep="")
            output[[plotname]] <- renderHighchart({
                highchart() %>%
                    hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
                    hc_title(text = "renderHighchart()") %>%
                    hc_xAxis(categories = seq_along(samp)) %>%
                    hc_add_series(
                        data = samp,
                        name = "Downloads"
                    )
            })
        })
    }
    
    output$rUI <- renderUI({
        
        output=list()
        for (i in 1:50) {
            n <- i # Make local variable
            plotname <- paste("plot", n , sep="")
            
            output[[plotname]] <- 
                highchart() %>%
                hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
                hc_title(text = "renderUI") %>%
                hc_xAxis(categories = seq_along(samp)) %>%
                hc_add_series(
                    data = samp,
                    name = "Downloads"
                )
        }
        hw_grid(output,ncol=3)
    })
})

app=shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)

profvis::profvis(runApp(app))
```

If I now look at the aggregated time of `output$plots` and `output$rUi` in profvis, I can see that the aggregated time for `output$plots` is indeed faster